# When is the character of a representation a character?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group with a complex, finite dimensional representation $r:G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$.

What is the condition to make $\operatorname{trace}(r(g))$ also a character of $G$, i.e., group homomorphism?

Comment: Iff $dim(V)=tr(r(1))=1$ then $r(g) v= trace(r(g))v$ and $r$ is a character of $G$.

Comment: Do you see how to construct a representation such that $tr(\rho(g)) = 2 tr(r(g))$ ? And $tr(\pi(g)) = tr(r(g))+tr(r(g^{-1}))+1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r(e)=id$ so $trace (r(e))= \dim V$, so it cannot be a group morphism unless $\dim V =1$, in which case it is a morphism

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be an *irreducible* $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$ affording the character $\chi$. Assume that $\chi(g)\chi(h)=\chi(gh)$ for all $g,h \in G$ (so $\chi$ is a homomorphism). Then in particular $\chi(g)\chi(g^{-1})=\chi(g)\overline{\chi(g)}=|\chi(g)|^2=\chi(1)$. But $1=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|\chi(g)|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}|G|\cdot\chi(1)$, hence $\chi$ is linear.